# basis of $\{f\in C^2([a,b]):f(a)=f(b)=0 \}$

Tags: functional-analysis

Regarding the Dirichlet Laplacian operator $L^{(D)}f=-\frac{d^2}{dx^2}f$ on the set $D(L^{(D)})=\{f\in C^2([a,b]):f(a)=f(b)=0 \}$ on the Hilbert space $L^2(a,b)$ one can show that it is essentially self-adjoint by showing that the family of vectors $e_n(x)=\left(\frac{2}{b-a}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}\sin(\frac{\pi n (x-a)}{b-a})$ is an orthonormal basis consisting of eigenvectors for $L^{(D)}$. The orthonormality and the eigenvector property is not difficult to show but how do I show that $(e_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a basis for $D(L^{(D)})$? I could assume that there is another function, say $e_\infty\in D(L^{(D)})$ that is orthonormal to all the other $e_n$ and show that a contradiction arises. But how do I tackle such a problem?

**EDIT:** $(e_n)$ shall even be a basis for $L^2(a,b)$

Comment: One viewpoint would be that you need to know that the resolvent of the Laplacian (restricted to your space...) is _compact_...

Comment: @paulgarrett And then applying some spectral theorem?

Comment: Oh, yes, exactly, apply the spectral theorem for compact self-adjoint operators.

Comment: @paulgarrett The problem I see there is that I would have to use it on $D(L^{(D)})$ since $L^{(D)}$ is only defined there. The spectral theorem would yield that $D(L^{(D)})=\text{ker}(L^{(D)})\oplus_2 \{e_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ and I'd have to deal with $\text{ker}(L^{(D)})$ and also I don't know if $e_n$ are all of the eigenvalues. There might be missing some. Furthermore the spectral theorem also yields that the limit of the eigenvalues tends to $0$ which is not the case here.

Comment: Ah, not applied to the unbounded operator, but to its resolvent. Its resolvent is a continuous operator, defined everywhere, and so on...

Comment: @paulgarrett So you mean, applying the spectral theorem to $L^{(D)}-\lambda Id$? But for which eigenvalues?

Comment: If/when $(L-\lambda)^{-1}$ exists and is compact, then it also exists and is compact for $\lambda\in\mathbb C$ off a discrete subset. Yes, this is a little theorem. This is pretty standard, e.g., in Kato's "Perturbation Theory", or substantial books on general functional analysis and operator theory.

Comment: Must you use those sines as your basis? Note that $\left<L^{(D)}\phi,\psi\right> = \left<\phi,L^{(D)}\psi\right> - \left.\phi'(x)\overline{\psi}(x) - \psi(x)\overline{\psi}'(x)\right|_{a}^{b}$, so one could choose $\phi(a) = \phi(b)$ and $\phi'(a) = \phi'(b)$ as BCs. Those BCs permit using the complex exponentials $\exp(2\pi i n(x - a)/(b-a))$ as eigenfunctions, and classical results ensure that they form a complete set for $L^2(a,b)$.

Comment: @JoeMac Yes, I would like to use the functions I've given. However those exponentials are very closely linked to the sines, aren't they?

Comment: @mathemagician99 There is a relation, but not a simple one. Note the $2\pi n$ in my exponents and $n\pi$ in your sine arguments. From the point-of-view of complex exponentials or the alternative sines-and-cosines basis ($\sin(2\pi n(x-a)/(b-a), \cos(2\pi n(x-a)/(b-a))$), you have no cosines and **twice the usual number** of sines. Requiring both endpoint values to be 0 **seems** strict, but I am not sure that it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prepare for a reference to established theorems instead of a nitty-gritty proof.

---

Your equation is just about the simplest possible [Sturm-Liouville problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%E2%80%93Liouville_theory) with separated boundary conditions. S-L theory ensures that the normalized eigenfunctions form an orthonormal basis for $L^2(a,b)$

Comment: Ah, I see. That was also what paul garett meant.

Comment: @mathemagician99 My goal was to confirm that you are correct about the completeness, and you can find the details of the proof in a wide variety of sources.